Spoof IP address on SQL Server Client
The following link describes spoofing of the Host Name and Application Name on SQL Server Client side (to the server)
Bypassing SQL Server Logon Trigger Restrictions
The trick is done while building the Connection String.
Question:
Can one spoof same way (connection string) the IP address? Or any other way?

You generally cannot spoof your IP address when interacting with the internet (or any other (private) network). If you send your outgoing packets with a wrong source IP they might get correctly processed initially but the response will not reach you because you faked your IP (also meaning that any kind of handshake process fails). You can use VPNs to hide your IP from the target server but now the VPN knows your IP.

I think it's time to let go of the login trigger. If you want to deal with ips, why not use Firewall rules. What are you trying to protect? Or is this a school exercise

Just use a VPN?

Thank You  siggemannen
But if I need to combine IPs with MS SQL Users, and the firewall cannot handle the later, and the IP is difficult to spoof - then why not the logon trigger?
regards
Altin
